# Programmatically change the sleep/suspend timeout on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, sleep, suspend

I am looking for a way to programmatically change the sleep/suspend timeout on Windows (XP) and Linux (Debian & Ubuntu) operating systems without having to reboot the system. I have spent a decent amount if time searching for solutions but have not found anything conclusive. Could someone point me in the right direction?